# Is it soon to start using Cordova PhoneGap 3.0?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, ripple

I am in the process of getting set up to develop for phoneGap. I downloaded the most recent version of phoneGap (version 3.0), installed it and built an ios app. Initially I debugged apps by deploying them to an actual iphone 5 and then looking at the console in Safari Web Inspector. This works great but I would now like to inspect my app using a browser, with out deploying to my iphone 5. According to the internet the tool for this is the Chrome plugin [ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) but ripple only supports PhoneGap 1.0 and 2.0 (i.e. not 3.0). I found a [patch](https://github.com/fastrde/stuff) that is supposed to help but I couldn't get it working.

This prefaces my question; is it soon to start using Cordova PhoneGap 3.0?

Comment: It's never too soon to move from 1.x (ahhh!) Or 2.x to the lasest version, IMO. The Cordova team only supports 2.9.x in terms of backporting fixes anyway, and then only major fixes. If you want to debug in the browser try the latest ripple that is now in apache. Or use android 4.4 and the chrome web inspector.

Comment: If you just want to debug with the browser, you can try [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is actually wrong.

The Ripple plugin that you use for (version 1,2) are actually old. The new official version of Ripple supports version 3. But its not yet availabe as the chrome extension.

Official Page: http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/

Refer the below link on how to use Ripple for version 3 of PhongeGap/Cordova.

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn